# Cauchy Riemann Eqn

Tags: complex-analysis

I need a bit of help as I'm stuck on this problem...this maybe simple..but.. I have to find all z ∈ C such that the function f(z) = z cos(z(bar)) satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann eqns.

So far I have worked out the following:

∂⁡u/∂⁡x= cos(x) - xsin(x) - ycos(x)sinh(y)

∂⁡u/∂⁡y =  xcos(x)sinh(y) - sin(x)[sinh(y) + ycosh(y)]

∂⁡v/∂⁡x = sin(x) + xcos(x) - ysin(x)cosh(y)

∂⁡v/∂⁡y = xsin(x)cosh(y) + cos(x)[xsinh(x)+cosh(x)]

Do I simply have to check whether ∂⁡u/∂⁡x= ∂⁡v/∂y and ∂⁡u/∂⁡y=-∂⁡v/∂⁡x, in order to find out if it satifies the C-R eqns?

Comment: Yes, that's what you have to check. If you already learned about the Wirtinger derivatives, it is however much easier to check where $\frac{\partial f}{\partial\overline{z}}$ vanishes.

Comment: As far as I can see they are not equal and therefore don't satisfy the C-R eqn. Is this correct?

Comment: I think you made a mistake when differentiating, by the way, what you have there looks wrong. But the conceptual misunderstanding is that you are asked for the points where the CR equations are satisfied, so you need to find the points where $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(z) = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}(z)$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(z) = - \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(z)$. Although the CR equations are generally not satisfied, at some points, they are. You shall determine which points these are.